# Choosing $\phi/\beta$ in Lateral-directional control design

Tags: flight-controls, autopilot

In designing the Lateral-directional controller for aircraft, there is a parameter called $\phi/\beta$ that is defined as the ratio of the magnitude of the bank angle to the sideslip envelopes in the dutch-roll mode. For example in MIL-STD-1797, a lot of requirements are based on this parameter. However, there is no clue how this parameter is chosen itself in the design process. How can one choose this parameter in the design process?